# How to insert 3d model in 2d image based on skeleton-like keypoints (thinking about same mesh transformation as in Deforming Bones)

Tags: python, bones

I'm new in Blender and 3d modeling in general. The task is as follows:

I have a pose estimation algorithm that can estimate such keypoints on image.
[image]

I want to be able to properly insert 3d model depending on those keypoints and implement it in python. I found out that bones from blender might be very useful for this purpose.

It may be very helpful if you shared some insights or steps to deal with such task.

Comment: do you mean that you have no other input than images? Maybe using opencv with some color filters (if color contrasts are possible) and determinate some feature points?

Comment: As input I'm using images and keypoints (json). 
I didn't quite understand what are feature points.

Comment: so the json provides all needed information? what about the images in this case? I think you should provide more details about what the json file contains.

Comment: The json provides the coordinates of this "skeleton" points you see on the picture above.

Comment: @EddudosKim 2D or 3D?

Comment: @RobinBetts, it is 2D keypoints. It's OpenPose python library. 
I think that I can't properly insert 3D model onto 2D image without any knowledge of depth from the image, right? At least seems like bones don't work that way.

Comment: Hi, Edduos, just checking .. with AI, there might be some informed guessing going on.

Comment: @EddudosKim Regarding depth, if you have fixed bone lengths (which you should), you can figure out the angle toward or away from the camera (but, can't decide between the two.)